# 3265: item not found in this collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an `MS Access` table, I have some attachments to each item.

I would like to save each attachment in a temporary directory through a `VBA` code.

The VBA code that I am trying to replicate is in this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm5fch0xaI4&t=306s

The problem is that I get the `error '3265' item not found in this collection` already when I am trying to assign a value to a `DAO.Recordset2` object.

Here my code.

[image]

```
Private Sub Carica_Dati()

Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
Dim SQL As String

SQL = " SELECT [Data Processing List].Department" & _
      " FROM [Data Processing List]" & _
      " WHERE ((([Data Processing List].Treatment)=""HR-002""))"

Set rsParent = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

If rsParent.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "no"
Else
    Set rsAttachment = rsParent!Document.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `Department` is your attachment field. In that case, you need to use `!Department`, and not `!Document`

`Set rsAttachment = rsParent!Department.Value`

If `Document` is your attachment field, you need to include it in your query:

```
SQL = " SELECT [Data Processing List].Department, [Document]" & _
      " FROM [Data Processing List]" & _
      " WHERE ((([Data Processing List].Treatment)=""HR-002""))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet your table `Data Processing List` doesn't have a field called `Document`.  That would be a bad name for a field anyways since *Document* is a reserved word.  (If you posted sample data then it we know for sure what the problem was.)  Check out [MCVE]